# Two problems about Google material icons

Tags: menu, icons, alignment, google-material-icons

I have two problems about Google material icons:

1. How can I align google material icons to the left or right side?
2. How can I put Google material icons front of any text in a side menu?

Comment: Give an example of your menu, otherwise it's too broad.

Comment: Just i want to know how can i align google material icons when i use <i> tag like this : <i class="material-icons">folder</i>

Comment: So you have, let's say, five icons and you want to align them all to the left, or right, of their container? What about the "side menu", is it just a <ul><li> list? An example would be better...

Comment: Yes for example five icons in a side menu and i want to align them all to the left or right side.in fact in want to know how can i align(to the left or right side) an icon when i use <i> tag?